# How to run android application in background

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to run application in background in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214825/how-to-run-application-in-background-in-android)

i am doing project using location manager if my location latitude and longitude equal to the same which is in database mobile profile should go to silent mode.so i need to keep on update my location using location manager.i did it .but if i close my app it's not working.
but my app should be working even though i close my app.i tried with async task its working when i close the app but after i switch to loud mode manually it's not changing to silent.i should also get notified when my app runs n background..please help.tks in advance

here is my code

```
public class ShowLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
      private TextView latituteField;
      private TextView longitudeField;
      private LocationManager locationManager;
      private String provider;
      double lat,lng;
      Location location;
      AudioManager mobilemode ;
        private Boolean flag = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        mobilemode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields

        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        if (flag) {

        if (location != null) {
          System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
          onLocationChanged(location);


          if((lat==12.905478)&&(lng==80.093358))
        {
            mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"VIBRATE profile activated ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
        else if ((lat==12.90080625)&&(lng==80.09210655))
        {
            mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);





            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SILENT profile activated !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //notification.setLatestEventInfo(ShowLocationActivity.this, "changed to silent mode", "because u r in office", pendingIntent);
              //  notificationManager.notify(i, notification);
        }
        else
        {
           mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"LOUD profile activated !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        }




        else {
          latituteField.setText("Location not available");
          longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }
    }
        else {
            alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                 Intent intent = new Intent( ShowLocationActivity.this,SetPreference.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                 checkPref();
                 return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
             }








        }

      private void checkPref(){

          SharedPreferences myPref

          = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ShowLocationActivity.this);

          String _pref =

                  "Option 1: " +  myPref.getBoolean("pref_opt1", true);


      }



      @Override

      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          checkPref();

      }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
         lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
      }


      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
      }

      public void rrr(View v)
      {

          DownloadTask n= new DownloadTask();
             n.doInBackground();
      }
      public void onDestroy()
      {
          super.onDestroy();
          Log.v("hhh","on destroy");
             DownloadTask n= new DownloadTask();
             n.doInBackground();
      }

      public Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
            boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(
                    contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gpsStatus) {
                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /*----------Method to create an AlertBox ------------- */
        protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("** Gps Status **")
                    .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // finish the current activity
                                    // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(myIntent);
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // cancel the dialog box
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {


            Log.v("hhh","back");
            onCreate(null);
            // onLocationChanged(location);
            /*
            lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
             lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
            latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));

            if (location != null) {
                  System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
                  onLocationChanged(location);


                  if((lat==12.905478)&&(lng==80.093358))
                {
                    mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"VIBRATE profile activated ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
                else if ((lat==12.90080625)&&(lng==80.09210655))
                {
                    mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);





                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SILENT profile activated !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //notification.setLatestEventInfo(ShowLocationActivity.this, "changed to silent mode", "because u r in office", pendingIntent);
                      //  notificationManager.notify(i, notification);
                }
                else
                {
                   mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"LOUD profile activated !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



                }




                else {
                  latituteField.setText("Location not available");
                  longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
                }






            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        */
            return null;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: User Android Component called [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: This question may answer what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have coded in Activity, I suggest you to changed it to [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). A Service is a component which runs in the background, without interacting with the user.

Have a look at Vogella's [Service Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Just Convert your Activity code into Android Service and it will work in background without any GUI.

Comment: yes service method works.but we also should use broad cast receivers to send update about location from service to activity

Comment: well even that can also run in background. i do same.